# What data type should I use in legacy code where the new type is unavailable?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, stringbuilder, idisposable, httpwebresponse

This code works (in modern versions of .NET):

```
public static string SendXMLFile(string xmlFilepath, string uri, int timeout)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        if (timeout < 0)
        {
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
            request.Timeout = timeout;
        }

        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            request.Abort();
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

However, on trying to use it in a DLL used by a Windows CE app that's tied to old versions of the Compact Framework and .NET, there are several problems. First, I tried to change the "var" to its explicit type; I tried changing this:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

...to this:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

...but that doesn't even work - the "HttpWebResponse" exhibits the dreaded squiggly red underscore syndrome.

Hovering over the squiggliness, I see, '*Cannot implicitly convert type 'HttpWebResponse' to 'System.IDisposable'*'

So I changed 'HttpWebResponse' to 'System.IDisposable' and the whole line went squiggly. What does it really want - a class that implements IDisposable? If so, which one is available/my best bet?

I also have problems with HttpWebRequest not having a ReadWriteTimeout property, and StringBuilder not having an AppendLine() method. Are there older versions of these members that will do "in a pinch"?

For now, I've done this regarding AppendLine:

```
sb.Append(line);
sb.Append("\r\n");
```

...and just commented out the ReadWriteTimout:

```
if (timeout < 0)
{
    //request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
    request.Timeout = timeout;
```

...but as to the IDisposable issue, I am doing a pretty fair Stonewall Jackson imitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    return response.ToString();
}
finally
{
    var disposableResponse = response as IDisposable;
    if(disposableResponse != null) disposableResponse.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: it's not of type `IDisposable` if I understand correctly

Comment: In trying this code, I had to change "var" to IDisposable, and even then "response as IDisposable" gives me "Use of unassigned local variable 'response'"

Comment: thumbmunkeys edit should fix the "unassigned variable" problem (that's what I get for using SO as a code editor).  This code will work for legacy systems where it's not IDisposable *and* for newer where it is, disposing where appropriate.  Basically a single code base that works with both versions.

Comment: I don't know why my brain wasn't working right with my previous response; the only thing I had to add to what's above to make it work for me is replacing "var" with "IDisposable"

Answer (score 1):

I think in the old version, `HttpWebResponse` is not disposable, this should be fixed by removing the `using` clause.

Comment: That gets it to compile anyway; I'll test it now.